# Solve the first order PDE using Lagrange method

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Let $u(x, y)$ be the solution of first order partial differential equation $$xu_x+(x^2+y)u_y=u, \ \text{for all}\ x, y\in \mathbb{R}$$satisfying $u(2, y)=y-4$. Then find the value of $u(1, 2)$.

My attempt: I started with Lagrange equations and write $$\frac{dx}{x}=\frac{dy}{x^2+y}=\frac{du}{u}$$
Using first and third equations, I get $x=au$ for some constant $a$. But I strucked further, as I wanted to solve second and third by making use of $x=au$ but unable to do so. Please help how to proceed further.

Comment: Do you need to use the Lagrange method? I would probably use a characteristic equation method which I think is related but I am not super familiar with this

Comment: Never mind I looked it up they are the same thing, I'll post a response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$xu_x+(x^2+y)u_y=u $$
$$\frac{dx}{x}=\frac{dy}{x^2+y}=\frac{du}{u}\quad\text{is OK.}$$
A first characteristic equation comes from solving $\frac{dx}{x}=\frac{du}{u}$

$x=au\quad$ is OK or equivalently with $\quad c_1=1/a$
$$u=c_1x$$
A second characteristic equation comes from solving $\quad\frac{dx}{x}=\frac{dy}{x^2+y}\quad\implies\quad \frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y}{x}+x\quad$ which is a first order linear ODE.
$$\frac{y}{x}-x=c_2$$
The general solution of the PDE is :
$$u=x\,F(\frac{y}{x}-x)$$
$F$ is an arbitrary function to be determined according to the condition $u(2,y)=y-4$. I suppose that you can do it.

Answer (score 1):

So the idea is that you want to move the solution from the boundary where the values are known ($u(2,y) = y-4$) to the rest of the domain. So your 'initial condition' for these ODEs should be when $x_0 = 2$ and $u_0 = y_0-4$, which allows you to solve for the constant $a$:
$$ 2 = x_0 = au_0 = a(y_0-4) \implies a = \frac{2}{y_0-4} \implies u = \left(\frac{y_0-4}{2}\right)x  $$
So if we can figure out what $y_0$ is we have a solution equation. To do this we need to solve
$$ \frac{dx}{x} = \frac{dy}{x^2 + y} \iff \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{x^2 + y}{x} = x + \frac{y}{x}  $$
which is actually the nonhomogenous linear ODE $y' - \frac{1}{x}y = x$. You can solve this through various methods, probably the simplest of which is to multiply through by the integrating factor $1/x$ to get
$$ 1 = \frac{y'}{x} - \frac{y}{x^2} = \left(\frac{y}{x}\right)' \implies \frac{y}{x} =  x + C \implies y = x^2 + Cx$$
where again we can solve for $C$ with the initial condition
$$y_0 = x_0^2 + Cx_0 = 4 + 2C \implies C = \frac{y_0 - 4}{2}.  $$
But then rearranging $y = x^2 + x\left(\frac{y_0-4}{2}\right)$ yields $\frac{y_0-4}{2} = \frac{y - x^2}{x}$
and so we finally arrive at
$$ u = \left(\frac{y_0-4}{2}\right)x = \left(\frac{y-x^2}{x}\right)x = y - x^2. $$
It is not difficult to verify that this is the correct solution.